# google analytics profile simple filter not working properly?

Tags: filter, google-analytics, profile

I have been at this for a few days now, can't figure out what's wrong.
About half of my website's traffic comes from a certain domain name (scavengerhunt.org).
I have set up a very simple filter to a profile aimed at showing only traffic from that domain.
I set the filter as Include Only - Traffic from the ISP domain - that contain - scavengerhunt.org

I can see no traffic in the reports (when I remove the filter I can see traffic of course).
Any ideas?
Ilan

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom filter to Include Only - Traffic from a **Hostname**.

The ISP domain is the user's ISP (Internet Service Provider) domain based on their IP address not your website domain.